# load AJAX page when scrollbar is 200px far from bottom of the window where window size may vary

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I have tried this condition so far.

```
'if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())'
```

so can anybody help me to get the solutuion .???

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if (($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height()) - $(document).outerHeight(true) > (-200)) {...}
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/USfP6/2/)

Comment: hy it also have some defect buddy

Comment: Nope, it's not defect at all, you're probably just using it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 200) {
            //initate ajax here
        }
    });
});
```